# How to be undetected using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web, bots, nike

My goal is to create nike account without being detected but when I go to "https://www.nike.com/login" with selenium I'm instant detected as a bot I tried many things but still doesn't work.
This is the error:

[image: z]

This is my config :

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

I am also using a modified chromedriver.exe like in this question : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver". Thank you if you help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you visit random pages before hand? Try to look as natural as possible. Fill your cookie jar. Make sure to use proxies (preferably good proxies that are not banned or something like that). Nike has a lot of good bot protections and they are constantly improving them.

Comment: And as always for creating bots try and prevent selenium. Because its not design for creating bots its design to test UIs.